# Is Func or Action faster than if-else or switch-case?

Tags: c#

I am implementing a business logic where comparison and code execution must be fast. Suppose I have a switch case for 1000 cases. Something like that

```
    public void DoWork(int num)
    {
        switch (num)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    function_1();
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    function_2();
                    break;
                }
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //UPTO 1000 CASES

            case 1000:
                {
                    function_1000();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Now if I use Func or Action instead of ABOVE code, would not it be faster ?? Please see code below

```
    //This array will be initialized previously
    Action[] actions = { new Action(function_1), new Action(function_2), /*....UPTO 1000....*/ new Action(function_1000) };
    public void DoWork(int num)
    {
        actions[num]();
    }
```

Now please tell me which one will work faster and why ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: Seems like premature optimization. You should choose the one which is more readable (which is opinion-based), and care about performance only when it's really a problem.

Comment: This type of question typically indicates that the person asking us has severe and fundamental misunderstandings about how you optimize code. (Hint: How do you think the compiler actually implements a big switch/case statement like that?)

Comment: The approach used here will not be the bottleneck in your application. Bottlenecks are usually going to be found at places where a service is called, a large amount of memory is required for reading or parsing, or an algorithm with high time complexity is involved.

Comment: @L.B for 1000 cases I cant differentiate the time difference. I just want to know if my 2nd approach will work faster.

Comment: @Arnab call your method 1000000 times.

Comment: @Arnab For what possible reason? What you want is code that is easy to understand, maintain, and debug. The optimizations you care about are algorithmic, not in the implementation.

Comment: Test it! You don't need to implement all 1000 cases to just create a stop watch and a loop.

Comment: A must-read when it comes to [Which is Faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Guys, I just tested it with 22000 cases, switch case is 10 times faster than Action.

Comment: @Arnab Are you saying you had a switch of 22,000 cases? Or did you loop through a case statement 22,000 times? Doing the loop `x` times and getting an average is what you want to be doing when benchmarking anything. Running 1 time here and there doesn't really tell you anything.

Answer (score 5):

Optimizing compilers already know how to use computed branches to implement `switch` statements where the control variable is an integral type and the cases are sequential.  In effect, this means the compiler is generating a table of function pointers already.

One advantage of the switch version is that the functions being called can be inlined if small enough, removing the function call (which is a bit more expensive than a local branch).  Inlining also enables further optimizations.  For this reason, compilers also sometimes turn indirect calls into conditional branches, an optimization known as *devirtualization*.

C# doesn't give you this optimization, but the .NET JIT compiler might.  It depends greatly on the architecture (x86, x64, ARM, or Itanium) and version, which you haven't bothered to mention.  Not that there will be a large performance difference if those functions are doing anything non-trivial.

The bottomline is the same as all underdescribed performance questions -- **You should do whichever is more maintainable, unless you have profiler evidence that this is a performance bottleneck.**

Answer (score 2):

While I will agree that a switch statement with 1000 options is almost certainly not a good thing for production code, and definitely very difficult to maintain, the question has merit regarding the performance of switch statements and Action delegates.

**Consider the following scenario** (which I've encountered more than once and which led me to this question).

- I'm constructing a class.
- The constructor can receive one of several options.
- Once I have an instance of the class, I need to call a certain method on the class 10 million times.

In this scenario **the question of whether a switch statement or a delegate (Action/Func) would perform better becomes relevant**.

Specifically, I can either put a switch statement in my class method to handle the various scenarios OR I can assign the appropriate delegate at the time of construction so that my class method only needs to make a call to the pre-assigned delegate.

Now, I'll probably need a switch statement during construction to assign the delegate, but I only have to do that once.

Then the question is: **Will it be faster to run a switch statement ten million times or to call a delegate method (as Action or Func) ten million times?**

This is not exactly the same question as the OPs, but one many of us are more likely to encounter.

Many will say right away that the delegate is faster because once it's defined it's just a single method call which is faster than a switch statement...

...or is it?

As mentioned in many other StackOverflow answers, switch optimizes itself a bit. For a large number of options it is essentially a hashset or dictionary.  In other words, *very* fast.

But how fast is a method call?  Well, it's certainly slower than no method call.

I'm not smart enough to look at the IL code and deduce by visual inspection whether one set of instructions is faster than another...

**So I tested it!**

Before I get to the scenario I just described, **I'll first present my results for the OP's scenario**...but with 50 options in the switch instead of 1000.  (Too much copy and paste! :)

**I got a different result than the OP.**  In short, based on the *exact* scenario and making sure I was comparing apples to apples, **I determined that the delegate approach was faster**.

```
OP's Scenario:
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
|      TEST NAME      | ITERATIONS | Time (ms) |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| Baseline            | 10 million |        67 |
| Switch (50 options) | 10 million |       258 |
| 50 Action Delegates | 10 million |       191 |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

1. **Baseline Test** - The baseline test performs a simple integer add operation 10 million times.
2. **OP's Switch (50)** - In this test, we called a DoWork method 10 million times. The DoWork method contained a switch statement with 50 options which each then called another method to perform a simple integer add.  (Like I said, I agree this sort of design is not optimal.)
3. **OP's Method Delegate (as an Action)** - In this test, we call a DoWork method 10 million times.  The DoWork method called a specific Action delegate from a pre-initialized array.  The delegate performed a simple integer add.

**Results:**  I actually expected that the delegate technique would be faster in this scenario and it is, 191ms to 258ms.  We have an extra step with the switch statement because it's evaluating the switch and *still* making method calls.  But that was how the problem was defined.  And, as described by others, architecture and internal optimizations may mean one machine performs differently than another.

**Perspective:** There's a 25% difference in the outcomes.  But let's be clear.  **There are *very* few scenarios where this difference matters.**  Both techniques in this case are screaming fast.

Now, let's get back to my scenario.

```
My Scenario 
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
|      TEST NAME      | ITERATIONS | Time (ms) |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| Switch (50 options) | 10 million |       192 |
| One Action Delegate | 10 million |        86 |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

1. **My Switch (50)** - In this test I call a method, DoWork, 10 million times.  Inside DoWork is a switch statement with 50 options.  Each option does a simple integer add inline.
2. **My single Action delegate** - In this test I chose a single method delegate and called it 10 million times.  Inside the delegate a simple integer add is performed.

(If you've forgotten, please re-read above to remember what my scenario is and why I compared these two tests.)

**RESULTS:** - Again, I expected that the single delegate call would be faster than evaluating the switch statement with inline code.  Still, I wasn't sure.  Now I am.  What this tells me is that:

1. If I have code that may be called many times (thousands or millions of times) that calling a single pre-defined delegate method is almost 3x faster than using a switch statement.
2. I will never have to worry about this again because both approaches are screamingly fast.

**TAKEAWAY:** By actually measuring the behavior we now have a solid set of numbers to look at rather than just speculating.  Maybe the numbers would be different on different machines, but we can still see that the differences are small for things that are already extremely fast.

In conclusion, I will echo some of the other answers:

When considering whether to use a switch statement or method delegates (and there are several legitimate scenarios where you may face this choice), you only have to worry about performance if you care about a few milliseconds.  Otherwise, use whatever keeps your code clean and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for testing this! This is exactly the kind of optimization I was considering for a project, and it's been difficult finding an answer elsewhere.